# xcorr versus finddelay for finding delay between signals

Tags: matlab, cross-correlation

Calculating the time delay between the two pulses illustrated [here](http://postimg.org/image/bsorzgt1z/), using the function `finddelay(pulse1,pulse2)`, I get the correct value of 8.73 nsec. However when I use `xcorr(pulse1,pulse2)`, the result is about 11.2 nsec... What am I doing wrong here?

xcorr:

```
r=xcorr(pulse1,pulse2); 
[a,b]=max(r);
delay=20/4096*b;
```

[here's](http://postimg.org/image/egdeiaian/) the plot for the cross correlation

finddelay:

```
delay=finddelay(v1,v2);
t=20/4096*delay;
```

In the first case delay=2308 and in the second one delay=1788

Comment: How have you get the delay with xcorr?

Comment: For a 20nsec window, with 4096 points/window, the delay is (20/4096)*c, where c is the position of the maximum of the xcorr() sequence (in my case c=2308)

Comment: Is it possible to put some data and some piece of code? There is a good example of how to do it properly in http://uk.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/xcorr.html. Try your piece of code against the one suggested, see if you get the same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your question you haven't mentioned sampling frequency since the `finddelay` and `xcorr` will give you the delay in number of samples.

Check this example,

```
Fs = 100;
L  = 1000;
t = (-L / 2 : 1 : L / 2) / Fs;
y1 = sinc(t);
y2 = sinc(t - 1);
plot(t,y1,'b'); hold on;
plot(t,y2,'m');
d1 = finddelay(y1,y2) / Fs;
[c,lags]=xcorr(y1,y2);
d2 = -(lags(c == max(c))) / Fs;  % minus is for nature of xcorr
```

[image]

Where the answer for both `d1` and `d2` is `1`.

Answer (score 0):

As implied by the answer above, your error is with your use of xcorr.  You need to ask for both the "c" values and for the "lags":

```
[c,lags]=xcorr(pulse1,pulse2);  %do the cross-correlation
[max_c,I]=max(x);  %find the best correlation
delay = lags(I);  %here is the delay in samples
```

Comment: Well... I just figured it out too! Nevertheless, thanks for the heads up! :)